# List comprehension with if conditional to get list of files of a specific type

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension, glob

Roughly following the logic for putting together list comprehensions with an if-else described in [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14638871/python-ternary-iteration-with-list-comprehension), I am trying to get a list of files with a specific extensions under a parent directory.

Here is the long form of the code:

```
mxd_list = []
for top_dir, dir_list, obj_list in os.walk(top_path):
    for obj in obj_list:
        if obj.endswith('.mxd'):
            mxd_list.append(os.path.join(top_dir, obj))
```

This is my current attempt at consolidating this using a list comprehension. Although it runs, the list is empty.

```
for top_dir, dir_list, obj_list in os.walk(top_path):
    mxd_list = [os.path.join(top_dir, obj) for obj in obj_list if obj.endswith('.mxd')]
```

Comment: That's not the ternary operator, that's part of the list comprehension syntax.

Comment: You're assigning, not appending, in every iteration of your outer loop?

Comment: Did you try glob.glob(top_path + '*.mxd')?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were quite near. You need to append to the list which is outside the loop

```
mxd_list = []
for top_dir, dir_list, obj_list in os.walk(top_path):
    mxd_list.extend([os.path.join(top_dir, obj) for obj in obj_list if obj.endswith('.mxd')])
```

The error is that - In every iteration of the outer for loop, the list comp would generate a list specific to that iteration only, thus you need to `extend` each of the list generated after every iteration to the outer variable, `mxd_list`.

Note - The `[` are redundant in the sense that removing them would make the contents a generator expression. That is the the statement can be written as `mxd_list.extend(os.path.join(top_dir, obj) for obj in obj_list if obj.endswith('.mxd'))`.

*Another Way of doing it* - Using [`glob.iglob`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html#glob.iglob)

[As Padraic mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28682226/list-comprehension-with-ternary-operator-to-get-list-of-files-of-a-specific-type/28682289?noredirect=1#comment45657769_28682289)

```
mxd_list = []
for top_dir, dir_list, obj_list in os.walk(top_path):
     mxd_list.extend(iglob(top_dir+"/*.mxd"))
```

Is a better way of doing it. But do not forget to `import` the module, i.e, `from glob import iglob`

Comment: You can use a generator expression for extend, save building a list.

Comment: Excellent, this is what I am looking for. Mostly I am trying to figure this out as an exercise in applying and learning list comprehensions. This illuminates what I am missing, the way the list is recreated at every directory found. Thank you for the help!

Comment: You can also use  `iglob(top_path+"*.mxd")` to find the files

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I've not used `iglob`, The nearest I have ever come to is `glob.glob`. Can you Please add it as an answer so that the OP can know? (*ulterior motive - So that I can learn*)

Comment: @BhargavRao no worries, I am not totally sure what the OP wants but some variation of that will work.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Yeah. We have to think of other people who view this post too!

Comment: @knu2xs With the help of Padraic, the answer is now even more complete. Do check the edit and the extra code snippet added :)

Answer (score 0):

The list of pathnames of the matching files can be computed with a single list comprehension

```
[os.path.join(d,f) for d,_,fl in os.walk(top) for f in fl if f.endswith(ext)]
```