# Printing File Names

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am very new to `python` and just installed `Eric6`  I am wanting to search a folder (and all sub dirs) to print the filename of any file that has the extension of `.pdf`  I have this as my syntax, but it errors saying

> The debugged program raised the exception unhandled FileNotFoundError
>   "[WinError 3] The system can not find the path specified 'C:'"
>   File: C:\Users\pcuser\EricDocs\Test.py, Line: 6

And this is the syntax I want to execute:

```
import os

results = []
testdir = "C:\Test"
for folder in testdir:
  for f in os.listdir(folder):
    if f.endswith('.pdf'):
        results.append(f)

print (results)
```

Comment: Is "C:\Test" your actual real directory name, or are you anonymizing it because the real directory is "C:\users\your_real_name" or something?

Comment: Why `for folder in testdir` ??? .. You are looping through `tesdir` string instead not each folder in `testdir`

Comment: @Kevin - that is the real directory I am wanting to scan.  I created a "Test" directory and placed a few diff file types in it to run this snippet on.

Comment: @IronFist - I am needing to do a recursive search, and once pushed to production environment the direcotry may/may not contain sub directories.

Comment: Related [List comprehension with if conditional to get list of files of a specific type](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28682226)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use the [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) module.

> The glob module finds all the pathnames matching a specified pattern

```
import glob, os
parent_dir = 'path/to/dir'
for pdf_file in glob.glob(os.path.join(parent_dir, '*.pdf')):
    print (pdf_file)
```

This will work on Windows and *nix platforms.

---

Just make sure that your path is fully escaped on windows, could be useful to use a raw string.

In your case, that would be:

```
import glob, os
parent_dir = r"C:\Test"
for pdf_file in glob.glob(os.path.join(parent_dir, '*.pdf')):
    print (pdf_file)
```

---

For only a list of filenames (not full paths, as per your comment) you can do this one-liner:

```
results = [os.path.basename(f) for f in glob.glob(os.path.join(parent_dir, '*.pdf')]
```

Comment: This code executes perfectly!  One question, can you use single or double quotes in python?

Comment: You can use either, it's just convention.

Comment: I also added in this as I only wanted filenames not full dir info (but I didn't say that in my question) print (os.path.basename(pdf_file))

Comment: @MichaelMormon: If you're going to print your code use single quotes because this will use less ink. :-)

Answer (score 4):

Right now, you search each character string inside of testdir's variable.

so it's searching the folder for values "C", ":", "\", "T" etc. You'll want to also escape your escape character like "C:\...\...\"

You probably was to use os.listdir(testdir) instead.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few problems in your code, take a look at how I've modified it below:

```
import os

results = []
testdir = "C:\\Test"
for f in os.listdir(testdir):
    if f.endswith('.pdf'):
        results.append(f)

print (results)
```

Note that I have escaped your path name, and removed your first `if folder...`. That wasn't getting the folders as you expected, but rather selecting a character of the path string one at a time.

You will need to modify the code to get it to look through all folders, this currently doesn't. Take a look at the [glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) module.

Answer (score 2):

Try running your Python script from `C:`. From the Command Prompt, you might wanna do this:

```
> cd C:\    
> python C:\Users\pcuser\EricDocs\Test.py
```

As pointed out by Tony Babarino, use `r"C:\Test"` instead of `"C:\Test"` in your code.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to escape the backslash on windows and you can use os.walk to get all the pdf files.

```
   for root,dirs,files in os.walk(testdir):
       for f in files:
           if f.endswith('.pdf'):
            results.append(f)
   print (results)
```

Answer (score 2):

You are basically iterating through the string `testdir` with the first `for` loop then passing each character to `os.listdir(folder)` does not make any sense then, just remove that first `for` loop and use [`fnmatch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fnmatch.html?highlight=fnmatch#fnmatch.fnmatch) method from `fnmatch` module:

```
import os
from fnmatch import fnmatch

ext = '*.pdf'
results = []
testdir = "C:\Test"
for f in os.listdir(testdir):
    if fnmatch(f, ext):
        results.append(f)

print (results)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `testdir = r"C:\Test"` instead of `testdir = "C:\Test"`. In python You have to escape special characters like for example `\`. You can escape them also with symbol '\' so it would be `"C:\\Test"`. By using `r"C:\Test"`, You are telling python to use *raw* string.

Also `for folder in testdir:` line doesn't make sense because `testdir` is a string so You are basically trying to iterate over a string.

Comment: Using raw strings to avoid accidental escape characters is a good idea in general, but I don't think it's responsible for the error here. "\T" doesn't escape to a tab character if the T is in caps.

Comment: delete `for folder in testdir:` line and it will work

Answer (score 1):

I had to mention the names of training images for my `Yolo` model,
Here's what i did to print names of all images which i kept for training `YoloV3` Model

```
import os

for root, dirs, files in os.walk("."):
    for filename in files:
        print(filename)
```

It prints out all the file names from the current directory